# Does Resource in Spring HATEOAS replace the DTOs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

I am bulding a REST API in Spring. So until now I have only reading services (GET). For this I used Spring HATEOAS to add links that referring to child elements.

Now I want to add some writing REST-Services. Usually DTOs are used in REST-Services and those are then mapped to the domain model.

So my question is: Can we just use resources from Spring HATEOAS as in the example below and do without DTOs? Or are resources intended for something else and I still need DTOs?

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> saveProduct(@RequestBody ProductResource product) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say that Spring HATEOAS doesn't replace DTOs: it builds on top of DTOs. So you can make your DTO class extend [`ResourceSupport`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.25.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/hateoas/ResourceSupport.html) or wrap it with [`Resource<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.25.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/hateoas/Resource.html).

Since Spring HATEOAS 1.0.0, released in late September 2019, [`ResourceSupport`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.25.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/hateoas/ResourceSupport.html) and [`Resource<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.25.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/hateoas/Resource.html) have been renamed to [`RepresentationModel`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/RepresentationModel.html) and [`EntityModel<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/EntityModel.html) respectively. Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/):

> **Representation models**
>
> The `ResourceSupport` / `Resource` / `Resources` / `PagedResources` group of classes never really felt appropriately named. After all, these types do not actually manifest resources but rather representation models that can be enriched with hypermedia information and affordances. Here’s how new names map to the old ones:
>
> - `ResourceSupport` is now `RepresentationModel`
> - `Resource` is now `EntityModel`
> - `Resources` is now `CollectionModel`
> - `PagedResources` is now `PagedModel`

---

What's important, however, is to keep the domain model decoupled from the API model.

The models that represent the *domain* of your application and the models that represent the *data handled by your API* are (or at least should be) *different concerns*. You don’t want to break your API clients when you add, remove or rename a field from the application domain model.

While your service layer operates over the domain/persistence models, your API controllers should operate over a different set of models. As your domain/persistence models evolve to support new business requirements, for example, you may want to create new versions of the API models to support these changes. You also may want to deprecate the old versions of your API as new versions are released. And it’s perfectly possible to achieve when the things are decoupled.

To minimize the boilerplate code of converting the domain model to the API model (and vice versa), you could rely on frameworks such as [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/). And you also could consider using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to generate getters, setters, `equals()`, `hashcode()` and `toString()` methods for you.

Comment: I have already ProductResource that extends ResourceSupport. Do you mean that I need an extra DTO class or is it sufficient to use ProductResource?

Comment: @hakson I understand you have two classes: `Product` (domain model) and `ProductResource` (which is a DTO that represents the model handled by your API). So you may not need other models.